unrecognized argument to ‘-flto=’ option
I am trying to install a simulation on my Linux Mint machine. Last step of the process was simply typing make in the terminal and the process would complete. But when I did that I recived an error stating this:
unrecognized argument to ‘-flto=’ option: ‘auto -ffat-lto-objects -flto=auto’

I have tried to comment out the options where -flto is mentioned in the CMakeCache.txt file. These two options were:
//MPI C compilation options
MPI_C_COMPILE_OPTIONS:STRING=-flto=auto;-ffat-lto-objects;-flto=auto


//MPI Fortran compilation options
MPI_Fortran_COMPILE_OPTIONS:STRING=-ffile-prefix-map=/build/mpich-0xgrG5/mpich-4.0=.;-flto=auto;-ffat-lto-objects;-flto=auto;-ffat-lto-objects;-fallow-invalid-boz;-fallow-argument-mismatch;-flto=auto;-ffat-lto-objects;-flto=auto


but as expected it didnt solve this problem and I recieved tons of errors that says undefined reference to 'ompi_mpi_*' Installation of mpi seems to be OK ,I can see the mpich folder in my system and mpirun --version command gives OpenMPI 5.0.4. My CMake version is 3.22.1 Any help is appreciated. Thanks for your time.
Edit: The problem seems to resolve with aligning mpicc, mpifort and mpirun (or mpiexec) as Gilles said in the comments. Just update the PATH and LD_LIBRARY_PATH variables from nano ./bashrc with the installation folder of your MPI. You may need to reinstall the application as I did.

CMakeCache.txt is generated when you run cmake. You want to try disabling that option in CMakeLists.txt. also, post the entire error message

You are mixing Open MPI with MPICH, and that will not end well. Choose one MPI library and use only this one.

What is the exact cmake command you used to configure your project? Which compiler are you trying to use? I experienced similar issues when trying cmake+mpich+clang. But, as Gilles pointed out, you will first need to get your MPI setup right and either pick mpich or openmpi

FC=mpifort CC=mpicc cmake .. -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=../CMC  this was the command that i used. I am using gcc and probably Gilles is right. I don't really have the knowledge of mpi libraries and might have mixed those two. The installation guide don't really suggest any of those two but some of the examples include openmpi. Probably I need to continue with OpenMPI.

make sure both mpifort and mpicc uses Open MPI like mpirun

The confusing thing about the error message is that it indicates that all MPI_C_COMPILE_OPTIONS are passed to the compiler as one string. The only reasonable explanation is that the variable is put in quotes. Can you find "$MPI_C_COMPILE_OPTIONS" somewhere in a CMakeLists.txt?

To deal with mpich vs openmpi, you should consistently use a suffix: mpicc.mpich + mpirun.mpich or mpicc.openmpi + mpirun.openmpi

Unfortunately there is no CMakeLists.txt in the build directory. There is only CMakeCache.txt and I think I have written all of the MPI related options. Probably the issue is caused by mixing openmpi and mpich like Gilles says. Need to figure out a way to correct my MPI setup I believe.
